# mongodb replica set config version error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I have three machine running on amazon cloud. I set the first primary set as follows

```
{
"_id" : "rs0",
"version" : 270805,
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017",
        "priority" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017"
    }
]
```

}

then the second machine will auto sync the config. however, the third machine will not synced the config.and all becomes [secondary]. when I set up the third machine rs conf using `re.reconfig(conf, {force: true})`. it will not set and throw error something like has a

> config version >= to the new cfg version; cannot change config

Comment: On which machine are you reconfiguring? The current primary or the other member?

Comment: primary, the first machine

Comment: No idea then from me, the only way I know how to get it is when/if the primary switched to secondary when you added the second machine and you're attempting to reconfigure on a secondary.

Comment: So you see the error message when you do the `rs.reconfig(conf)`? how did you get the `conf` object?

Comment: @yaoxing suppose when I rs.reconfig(conf) on primary, the secondary will auto update/sync the conf(the same as primary) which what the second machine is doing. but the other secondary/third machine does not accept the reconfig from primary and still has previous conf which is different from the first and second machine.

Comment: @yaoxing I get the conf object by using rs.conf()

Comment: @yaoxing, I tried to manually reconfig the third machine. however, the version number is less than the primary one, thats why it does not allow me to reconfig it as the same as primary. and it does not auto sync too.

Comment: but as I know you can't reconfig in the secondaries. it will always fail. You can only do that to primary. what's the result of `rs.status()`?